# How can I calculate the differentiation of qi in mathematica if I have the sum in the equation?

Tags: difference-equations

[image]How can I calculate the partial differentiation of qi in the next equation?

Comment: Please post your Mathematica code instead of picture.

Comment: It is not a very good idea to use the same `i` both for the summation index, and a separate an unrelated index outside of the sum. Use different letter for these two distinct things (e.g. `i` and `j`). This will make the meaning of the formula clearer, and will also allow Mathematica to complete the differentiation.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Both qi (outside the brackets and in the sum) are the same and this is the variable. We have qi products where i can be from 1 to n. So without the brackets the variable is multiplying with the sum of the variables. When I do the differentiation in mathematica e.g. D[F,qi] the software differentiates only the variable outside the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same `i` both for the summation index and an unrelated index outside the sum. This muddies the meaning of the formula. That said, Mathematica can apparently compute the partial derivative with or without correcting this problem.

Example with a simpler formula:

```
D[
 q[j] (1 + Sum[q[i], {i, n}]),
 q[j]
]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much